# How to make Remote Desktop Services Deployment visible in Windows 2012R2 server manager when logging with a different user?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, high-availability, remote-desktop-services, mmc

We have an high availability setup for Remote Desktop Services  (Windows 2012R2 datacenter edition) all servers are member of "Domain A":

- 2 Domain controllers                : DCA01, DCA02
- 1 Gateway server                    : RDGWA01
- 2 Remote Desktop Connection Brokers : RDCBA01, RDCBA02 (members of RDCBAHA cluster)
- 3 Remote Desktop Session Hosts      :    RDSHA01, RDSHA02, RDASH03 (members of RDSHHA cluster)

Several Remote Desktop Session Collections are configured and visible in Server Manager when I log on to both Remote Desktop Connection Brokers (RDCBA01, RDCBA02) under a domain account user "legacyadmin01".

I created a new security Group on "Domain A" for : "newadmingroup01" with one member "newadminuser01". "newadmingroup01" is a member of Domains Administrators group.

When I log on to both Connections Brokers (RDCBA01, RDCBA02) using the new account "newadminuser01" and navigate to Remote Desktop services role in Server Manager, now I can't see session Collections or other members of the RDS deployment.

The server manager view of Remote Desktop Services role (on (RDCBA01 and RDCBA02) seems to be tied to current user, but I can't figure out in what way (GPO, group membership...).

How to ensure that "newadminuser01" (or other tailored admin accounts) is able to see & manage Remote Desktop Services server members and Collections in Server Manager ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to right click on the server and select manage as and then use a domain admin credential